# Javascript how to guide user through the usage flow

Tags: javascript

Does anybody knows if exists a javascript library that guides the user through a sequence of steps?

i.e., showing him messages and arrows to give him instructions of where to click, type, drag or how to continue in order to achieve something.

I know its possible to do it with jquery, or any other, but I was hopping to avoid to write a bunch of code by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of projects. I have used Guiders and has worked out well.

http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/

https://github.com/jeff-optimizely/Guiders-JS